# How to allow any user to preview its database in cloudkit dashboard?

Tags: cloudkit, dashboard

Is it possible that users of my app can see its own database using cloudkit dashboard or any other way? I need to help someone with one issue, and I need to know what is in its database. Can I do it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit dashboard is only accessible by a developer account, and will only show the data associated with that developer account. Otherwise you see nothing more than a message 'You are not a member of a Developer Team'.

Public access to an iCloud database is possible by using CloudKit JS. This requires an API Token or a server-to-server key. More info here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs.